# Default permissions that are granted when using InstalledPackage?

Tags: metadata-api, ant, installedpackage

I have been using [InstalledPackage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_installedpackage.htm) for a while now as a quick way to install managed packages in different orgs without having to log in. It appears that the default permissions that are granted is **Install for All Users**. This would be the same as clicking the option below when installing a managed package through the UI.

[image]

I had assumed the default would of been **Install for Admins Only** which is the default when installing manually in the UI.

**Question:** Is there anyway to use [InstalledPackage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_installedpackage.htm) with the **Install for Admins Only** option?

For more information on InstalledPackage, have a look at [this post](http://andyinthecloud.com/2013/06/23/look-ma-no-hands-automating-install-and-uninstall-of-packages/) by Andrew Fawcett

**Update:**

It appears that for a clean install of a managed package the **Install for All Users** option is used. When a managed package is being upgraded the **Install for Admins Only** option is used.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what Salesforce support came back with:

> As of now there is no documentation available which can provide the
>   insight of the default permission about the installation of the
>   managed package via ANT. However, the InstalledPackage complexType in
>   udd-types.xml:
>
> ```
> <complexType name="InstalledPackage" owner="ISV - Packaging" extends="Metadata">
> <attribute name="apvId" type="string"/>
> <attribute name="nameConflictResolution" type="string"/>
> <attribute name="packageInstallSource" type="string"/>
> <attribute name="password" type="string"/>
> <relationship name="profileMappings" type="ProfileMapping"/>
> <attribute name="securityType" type="string"/>
> <attribute name="versionNumber" type="string" required="true"/>
> </complexType>
> ```
>
> there we can specify one attribute as securityType which can be used
>   in the further to specify the permission. Here is that SecurityType
>   enum that is used in the InstalledPackage metadata code that sets the
>   value:
>
> ```
> public enum SecurityType {
> FULL("full"), 
> NONE("none"), 
> CUSTOM("custom"), 
> PUSH("push");
> ```
>
> "admin only" would correspond to "none" and "all users" would be
>   "full"
>
> However, just to iterate again, unfortunately there no documentation
>   available about the default permission provided while installing via
>   ANT.